# SQL query returning a column of 1 if a condition is met and 0 otherwise

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've created a nice query to watch all the unique IPs entering my site. The schema is as follows:

Page_Statistic - Contains data on each page hit (one record per hit).

- page_statistic_id.
- ip - ip address of visitor.
- tag - used to record special things, like "demo" if they tried the demo.
- url - of the page they visited.
- requested_on - time of visit.

Ip_Location_Info - Contains location data on each visitor (one record per ip).

- ip
- country
- region
- city
- zip

I want to get all the unique IP addresses, with locations, number of visits, time range, and whether they tried the demo on my website - and this last part is what I'm having trouble with. I want a 1 if they've tried the demo, and 0 if they haven't. An IP has tried the demo iff a tupple exists in Page_Statistic with tag set to 'demo'.

I've created the following query which solves this:

```
WITH uniqueips(frst, lst, ip, visits) AS
(
    SELECT MIN(requested_on), MAX(requested_on), ip, count(*) AS visits
    FROM Page_Statistic p
    GROUP BY ip
),
tried_demo(ip, tried_demo) AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ip.ip, ISNULL(p.page_statistic_id - p.page_statistic_id + 1, 0) 
    FROM uniqueips ip
    LEFT JOIN Page_Statistic p ON p.ip = ip.ip AND p.tag = 'demo'
)
SELECT 
i.*, ip.frst AS first_appeared_on, 
    ip.lst AS last_appeared_on, 
    ip.visits,
    d.tried_demo
FROM Ip_Location_Info i
JOIN uniqueips ip ON ip.ip = i.ip
JOIN tried_demo d ON ip.ip = d.ip
ORDER BY ip.frst
```

But the ugly part is where I set the 1 or 0 for tried_demo.

```
ISNULL(p.page_statistic_id - p.page_statistic_id + 1, 0)
```

This works because if p.page_statistic_id is null, adding 1 to null is null so isnull will return the second item in the list of params (0). It's such a hack! What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: did you try `(CASE WHEN p.page_statistic_id ISNULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS tried_demo` ? I'm not a sql-server expert, but I think that's ANSI standard.

Comment: Yes, use case and it should work on sqlserver and oracle etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it works, so that's good, but if you wanted to change it, you could change it to

```
case when p.page_statistic_id is null then 0 else 1 end
```

OR

change your tried_demo CTE to this

```
tried_demo(ip, tried_demo) AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT p.ip, cast(1 as bit) 
    FROM Page_Statistic 
    WHERE p.tag = 'demo'
)
```

then your select can be like this

```
SELECT 
i.*, ip.frst AS first_appeared_on, 
    ip.lst AS last_appeared_on, 
    ip.visits,
    coalesce(d.tried_demo,0) as tried_demo
FROM Ip_Location_Info i
JOIN uniqueips ip ON ip.ip = i.ip
LEFT JOIN tried_demo d ON ip.ip = d.ip
ORDER BY ip.frst
```